# Custom splitting of XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XML structure as below as part of a mapping tool step.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://google.com/z/Z/SplitAndMerge">
  <multimap:Message1>
    <Response>
      <Employment><status>OK</status></Employment>
    </Responses>
    <Responses>
      <Term><status>OK</status></Term>
    </Responses>
  </multimap:Message1>
</multimap:Messages>
```

I need to separate each of the Response into separate Message numbers as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://google.com/z/Z/SplitAndMerge">
  <multimap:Message1>
    <Response>
      <Employment><status>OK</status></Employment>
    </Responses>
  </multimap:Message1>
  <multimap:Message2>
    <Responses>
      <Term><status>OK</status></Term>
    </Responses>
  </multimap:Message2>
</multimap:Messages>
```

Is there a way to achieve this using XSLT?

Answer (score 1):

You can process each `Response` (or `Responses`, your sample is not consistent) and wrap it into a Message element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*/Response"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Response">
      <xsl:element name="multimap:Message{position()}" xmlns:multimap="http://google.com/z/Z/SplitAndMerge">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyY

That is XSLT 3, if you use an XSLT 2 processor you need to replace the `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="multimap:Messages">
        <xsl:element name="multimap:Messages">
        <xsl:for-each select="multimap:Message1/Responses">
            <xsl:element name="{concat('multimap:Message',position())}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```